# how to find the minimum and maximum of a column that changes according to another row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a data frame that has 3 columns and looks like this.

```
stations  neighbourhoods   Distance
     9              68     0.429490
     9              74     0.542039
     9              66     0.604525
     20            504     0.710707
     20             83     0.785087 
     28             31     7.116540
     28             30     7.839042
     28             34     9.190559
     28             26     10.320423
```

As you can see, stations column consists of 3 groups = 9,20,28. They all have corresponding distances according to a neighbourhood. The distances are already sorted according to their respective stations. What I want to achieve is to extract each minimum and maximum value according to their station, and put it into another dataframe.

Desired dataframe must look like this.

```
stations  Minimum Distance   Maximum distance
    9          0.429490       0.604525 
    20         0.710707       0.785087 
    28         7.116540       10.320423
```

So far I have tried this code `df_max = df.groupby('Distance').idxmax()` for max amounts but it did not work. How can I go on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `df.groupby('stations')['Distance'].agg(['min', 'max'])`

Comment: or `df.groupby(['stations '])['Distance'].transform(max)` and `df.groupby(['stations '])['Distance'].transform(max)` ?

Comment: @mozway how does it work with agg? I'm asking because I don't see any methods that are used to find min or max...

Comment: @cold_away I provided a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`+`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `min`/`max`:

```
out = df.groupby('stations')['Distance'].agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   stations       min        max
0         9  0.429490   0.604525
1        20  0.710707   0.785087
2        28  7.116540  10.320423
```

Or using named aggregation:

```
(df.groupby('stations')
   .agg(**{'Minimum Distance': ('Distance', 'min'),
           'Maximum distance': ('Distance', 'max')})
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   stations  Minimum Distance  Maximum distance
0         9          0.429490          0.604525
1        20          0.710707          0.785087
2        28          7.116540         10.320423
```